# how to return an ICollection<T> with the .net neo4j Client

Tags: .net, neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm trying to return a result list from my cypher query using the .net neo4j client and getting a "Does not contain a definition for ToList()" error.  Am I doing this incorrectly?

```
public async ICollection<App> getWishList(string uname)
{

    var query = client.Cypher.StartWithNodeIndexLookup("root", AUTOINDEX, PRIMARYINDEX, uname)
        .Match("root-[:WishList]-apps")
        .Return<ICollection<App>>("apps");

    var results = await query.ResultsAsync;
    return results.ToList<App>();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it was a simple answer.

I need to set the return type to just "App" instead of "ICollection" since the query already returns a collection.

```
var query = client.Cypher.StartWithNodeIndexLookup("root", AUTOINDEX, PrimaryIndexKey, uname)
            .Match("root-[:WishList]-apps")
            .Return<App>("apps");

        var results = await query.ResultsAsync;
        return results.ToList();
```

Comment: It might be clearer if you used "app" instead of "apps" in your MATCH clause there. Your match describes a single app node. You then have multiple matches. The return call says 'give me that "app" node, pushed into a .NET "App" type, for each result in the set'.